# BusyIndicator control

Tags: windows-phone-7

It seems that the phone control toolkit is missing the BusyIndicator control.
Does someone know about one ? 
does something else specific exists for WP7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you seen the ProgressBar control? You can use the ProgressBar control to show that your application is busy doing something. It is recommended that you use [PerformanceProgressBar by Jeff Wilcox](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/) (Remember to read his [follow up post](https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/progressbarperftips2/) too, it is important to consider IsIndeterminate and its value).

If you wanted to create a splash screen with a progress bar in it, [check out this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications). Alex also shows how to customize the progress dialog in [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/creating-progress-dialog-for-wp7).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like the splash screen sample http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx How would you use it in a mvvm approch ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I haven't used the sample you like in an MVVM application. However, I have used the PerformanceProgressBar in an application with MVVMLight, here is the blog post and sample code link (from my blog) - http://indyfromoz.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/windows-phone-7-listbox-pagination-with-mvvmlight-applicationbar/. You can have the popup splash screen in a Grid whose visibility is data bound to a dependency property in the view model. In StartLoadingData, set the property to true, and, in backroungWorker_RunWorkerCompleted, set the property to false, thereby hiding the grid. Is this clear?